# INotifyPropertyChanged value not updating value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, inotifypropertychanged

I have scratched my head 2 days now. Though I am new to .NET, I have read over 20 posts and questions, and I think my code should work. Some please throw light.

XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Name="testgrid" Text="{Binding textsource, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textbind tb = new textbind();
    tb.textsource = "one"; //one is displayed in the textbox.
    testgrid.DataContext = tb;
}
```

And:

```
public class textbind : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
          {
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
          }
        }

    private string a=string.Empty;
    public textbind()
    {

    }


    public string textsource
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            if (value != a)
            {
                a = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(textsource);
            }
        }


         }
}
```

Changing property:

```
public class changevalue
{
   //code doing things. this class is initialized by some other processes. 
     textbind tb1 = new textbind();
     tb1.textsource = "two"; // no updates to two in the text box.
}
```

What I believed is that every time I change textsource property, it will reflect change in the textbox, but it doesnt happen. Soneone please help.

thanks.

Comment: It won't fix the specific issue but you should really change NotifyPropertyChanged to be `var handler = PropertyChanged; if (handler!=null) { handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));}` to help avoid a threading issue where PropertyChanged could go to null between the test and the execution.

Comment: [Learn to debug first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Comment: I'm willing to bet good money that if you look in your Output window you'll see a binding error, either when starting the app or when updating the value. This is just a nicer way of saying what HB said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are editing a completely different object to your bound object.

Aslong as your are in your main window class you can do

```
((textbind)testgrid.DataContext).textsource = "two";
```

if you are not in your mainwindow class you will need to make sure you pass the instance of textbind that you put into the datacontext to whichever method is doing the update.

Additionally you need to change your implementation of textsource to

```
public string textsource
{
  get { return a; }
  set
  {
    if (value != a)
    {
      a = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("textsource");
    }
  }
}
```

The name of the changed property needs to be passed to notifypropertychanged not it's value.

Update in response to new comment by Naresh.

You will need to track the instance and pass it around in your code, so for example in your change value class either do something like

```
public class changevalue {
 public void doChange(textbind source) {
     source.textsource = "two"; // no updates to two in the text box.
 }
}
```

You will then need to pass the textbind instance into your doChange function, ie if calling from mainform.

Or you could do

```
public class changevalue {
   public textbind source {get; private set;}

   public changevalue() {
      this.source = new textbind();
   }

   public void doChange() {
     source.textsource = "two"; // no updates to two in the text box.
   }
}
```

Then where ever you initialize your changevalue class you need to have a reference to your form.  Then you can do

```
var myChangeValue = new changevalue();
mymainform.DataContext = myChangeValue.source;
```

Comment: yes. I know the mistake now.

Comment: could you please provide a bit more information about passing instance to another method? thanks

Comment: ahh, i didnt see you updated. though i finally got what i wanted. as you said, passed reference. thanks a ton. it took me a lot of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (value != a)
{
    a = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("textsource");
}
```

you were passing textsource as variable and NotifyPropertyChanged was raising for actual value of textsource. Instead you should pass it's name, "textsource".

Comment: @Naresh: If you think this makes no difference you have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is bound to one single instance of `textbind` object (in your case, `tb`). If you'll change that object, it will reflect in the view:

```
tb.textsource = "new value";
```

But what you're doing is creating a new `textbind` object (`tb1`) which is not bound to the view, expecting it to modify the view when it changes, and that's not how things work. For it to work you'd have to set `tb1` to be your new `DataContext`; however, what you should really do is simply change the `textbind` property of the originally bound object.

Also, as @Nightwish91 has mentioned, your `NotifyPropertyChanged` call should look like this

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("textsource");
```

Otherwise, the view will get incorrect property change notifications and won't update as expected.

Comment: i get what you said. but then how do I do it? every time change context? i am struck at implementation.

Comment: See my updated answer - you should keep the same DataContext, but modify the original `textbind` instance.

Comment: @Naresh Get the *existing* object from the DataContext and change it: `((textbind)testgrid.DataContext).textsource = "new value";`. Combine **both answers** to make things work.